# Render child elements inside specific block

Tags: html, polymer, dart-polymer

I am wondering how can I render child elements in a specific block inside my custom polymer component. E.g

This is the usage of my custom component:

```
<my-custom>
    <div>stuff to render</div>
</my-custom>
```

The declaration of my custom component:

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom" noscript>
    <template>
        <div id="stuffToRenderWrapper">
            <content />
        </div>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Using the above code, my dom looks something like the following.

```
<div>Stuff to render</div>
<div id="stuffToRenderWrapper"></div>
```

well the id:stuffToRenderWrapper is inside the shadow dom and the div:Stuff to render is not. The question here is how do I render the stuff to render inside the wrapper?

Comment: Your example looks correct. What makes you think that the insertion into `<content>` isn't working? How are you confirming that?

Comment: Your example should be working. Could you test with <content></content> instead of short tag version. Try also to leave out the id of div and try with some different wrapper element (<span></span)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can use a self closing `<content>` element.

This should work:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      #stuffToRender ::content h1 {
        color: red;
      }
      #stuffToRender ::content h2 {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="stuffToRender">
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<x-foo>
  <h1>I am an h1</h1>
  <h2>I am an h2</h2>
</x-foo>
```

Make sure to add [polyfill-next-selector](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#at-polyfill) to those ::content styles so they work in other browsers